# UAC Application Manifest when you don't know runtime application name

Tags: uac, manifest, elevated-privileges

I have a program that works fine if UAC is turned off.  I want to be able to use a manifest to have it simply request elevation privileges when it launches.

The instructions from MS say "The application manifest file should have the same name as the target executable file with a .manifest extension" and that's probably why I am not having any success.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

My program is built as "one.exe" and then {SmartAssembly} renames it to "two.exe" and then the users are encouraged to rename it again.  I can't tell if that matters or which executable name to use.

Does anyone know if what I want is even possible?  If not, is there a way to have the app tell the user that the problem us UAC related?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Embed the manifest as a resource inside your .exe